# Mega menu issue with product zoom

Tags: magento2, javascript, css, zoom, megamenu

I am using Magento 2.2.6 on the product page, When you view a product, and then you go to Products Menu, once the mega menu is shown up, move mouse to the menu item over the product picture area, then you will see that you cannot move your mouse to a proper menu item.

I have tried solutions on below mentioned answered but it does not work:

[Product image zoom issue on product details page when drop-down menu have overlap area with it](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/227354/product-image-zoom-issue-on-product-details-page-when-drop-down-menu-have-overla)

Comment: Website link : https://tinyurl.com/yb77gkjh